# This is a qustion about STM32F407VET6's Flash memory area over the 512kb

Tags: stm32, stm32f4, flash-memory

I'm currently using stm32f407vgt6 blackboard because the board using existing stm32f407vgt6 has been discontinued. I modified Lcd, touch, rtc, etc. and program ported normally. One of the differences between the two boards is that the existing one is 1MB of flash memory, and the vet6 blackboard is 512kbyte. Existing programs show sector 8,9 area (0x08080000, 0x080A0000) when looking at memory in debug mode, and I can see that the data is stored normally and stored after reboot, but this area is already over 512kb, but I don't know what area it is, so I'm thinking about whether or not to move it. If anyone knows what area this area is, I'd appreciate it.

I'm expecting accurate area of flash memory and over 512kb area

[image]

Comment: This is your program, we don't know what those data are. Look at the mapfile.

Comment: The only thing I found in docs is that F407Vx can have 512kB or 1024kB of Flash memory, I failed to find a strict 512kB upper boundary for any of them. Why did you decide that one of your MCU is 512 and the other is 1024? Also, I think CubeProgrammer can show actual size of Flash, check what it says.

Comment: cube programmer says flash memory size 512Kb ,  upper mentioned why my data is saved none flash memory area and act like flash ? is it reserved or something?  i'm a engineer of dron company , this product will mass production.  so i'm very carefully deal with it . thanks for your help beforehand

Comment: Since the program memory does not occupy a large amount of space in the selection of the board, it was determined that 512kb would be sufficient, so a popular board (stm32f407ve), which is used a little more, was used.